# Optimal path through one-hot vectors

Tags: python, math

I have a collection of one-hot vectors (in numpy)

`[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0] [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0] [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0] [0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]]`

My goal is to find the optimal path to reach all of the vectors, starting from the first vector (which is all 0's), which minimizes the number of steps. The path does not need to be continuous (ie if each vector has only one 1, then the number of steps can just be the number of non-zero vectors).

Is there any existing method that optimizes this? It's kind of like a shortest path problem.

Comment: What is a "step"?

Comment: Perhaps you could give a smaller example (for example with 5 one-hot vectors, and 4 bits per vector), and show us an optimal path on that example and how you are counting the steps and why that path is optimal.